# Issue in reloading tableView(SplitViewController) in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

In my app, am using `splitViewController` concept for my contacts page.

In my `rootViewController(ContactTableView_iPad.m)` i want to reload my tableview on the click of filter button. But eventhough i have given the code

`[self.tableView reloadData]`

my tableView is not getting reloaded.

i even tried few other codes in order to reload my tableView. I have given my entire code in the following link.

[Click here to view my code](http://pastebin.com/VefNRUUy)

Comment: have you set the tableview datasource and delegete to self ?

Comment: Yes Friend.. I have set the delegate and datasource through .xib file..

Comment: @BhavikKama : Kindly review my entire code and suggest me a solution pls..

Comment: Are the Delegate methods called on the filter selection?

Comment: I think that is where the problem is. When the splitViewController is loaded for the first time, we pass a default filter value and get the array values and all the three delegate methods are executed properly.
Now when we change the filter value and fetch the data for array from DB and call [self.tableView reloadData] , none of the delegate methods are called and hence the tableView is not reloaded.